# How do I use a Match function and reference the row number it returns?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, subtraction

I'll do my best to explain this.  I'm working in a spreadsheet that contains roughly 150 columns and 2,500 rows.  In column D, there is an identification number that is unique to that line.  I need to filter on that column for a specific ID number (say B5555) then subtract the value in column AH of that row from the values in columns AB, O and M of that row.  Then I need to zero out the value in column AH.

Filtering for the ID number is no problem but B5555 could show up in any row.  IE, one week it shows up in row 2,300 and the next it is in 1,500, so I can't just make the formula say subtract AH2300 from AB 2300 because the next week that will act on the wrong cells.  How do I make the formulas subtract specifically from the line that B5555 shows up in?  The code I have so far only filters for that ID number so it isn't much but is shown below.  I'm new to VBA os nay help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub ManualAdjustments()

Dim wbTarget            As Workbook
Dim wbThis              As Workbook
Dim strName             As String
Dim rownum              As Integer

Set wbTarget = Workbooks("Weekly Data")

wbTarget.Activate

Worksheets("Raw").Activate

rownum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("B5555", 
Sheets("Raw").Range("D:D"), 0)
```

The above code is what I have so far. How do I reference "rownum" in a simple subtraction formula?  Would it be: Worksheets("Raw").Range("AHrownum")-Worksheets("Raw").Range("ABrownum")

Comment: You could use Range.Find to get the cell in that column where id found and then use the found cell's address or go with R1C1 formula.

Comment: Just to note that match returns the position number of thevitem in the list - so if your list starts in A1 then the position number will be the same as the row number but if the list starts in cell A12 then you need an offset....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this as below:

```
Sub ManualAdjustments()
Dim rownum As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Raw")

'Get the row number where value "B5555" is found in Column D
rownum = ws.Range("D:D").Find(What:="B5555", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row

'Subtract AH minus AB, O & M
NewValue = ws.Range("AH" & rownum) - ws.Range("AB" & rownum) - ws.Range("O" & rownum) - ws.Range("M" & rownum)

MsgBox "Your New Value is: " & NewValue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach:

```
Sub ManualAdjustments()

    Dim wbTarget            As Workbook
    Dim shtTarget           As Worksheet
    Dim wbThis              As Workbook
    Dim strName             As String
    Dim rownum              As Long '<<< safer never to use Integer...

    Set wbTarget = Workbooks("Weekly Data")
    Set shtTarget = wbTarget.Sheets("Raw")

   'no "worksheetfunction" = no runtime error if no match
    rownum = Application.Match("B5555", shtTarget.Range("D:D"), 0)

    If Not IsError(rowNum) Then '<< test for successful match here
        With shtTarget.Rows(rownum) 

            'Here Range() is *relative to the row*
            .Range("C1").Value = .Range("A1").value = .Range("B1").Value

        End With

    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: `rownum` should be a `Variant` to hand the `#Error` value, and then cast to a `Long` otherwise. My understanding is that the `Long` data type cannot handle when a `Error` data type is passed to it , and it will error out.